# sqlDatasource and sqlCacheDependancy

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcachedependency

this is my `sqldatasource`:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" CacheDuration="1" 
    CacheKeyDependency="Test_Tbl_Test" ConnectionString="<%$ 
    ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" EnableCaching="True" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [address] FROM [Tbl_Test]" 
SqlCacheDependency="CommandNotification"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

in global.ascx:

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        string dsn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start( dsn );

    }
```

every thing is good and caching work good but i want when i changed data in database the datasource refreshed without press any button on browser. i did it last but i forget it now! what can i do?(all of page controls is in `updatapanel` with timer)